# Setting Docker container hostname on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to set the hostname for a Docker container deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk manually. You can set the hostname when spinning up a container with `docker run -h HOSTNAME`, but I can't figure out how (or even if) to pass custom arguments to the `docker run` command.

The [Dockerrun.aws.json](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) file seems a likely candidate, but there are no documented keys that do what I want.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this is not supported out of the box.

A possible hack here is to exploit EB's poor parsing of environment variables. You can setup an environment variable such as:
`PARAM1=dummy -h MYHOSTNAME`
EB doesn't quote the parameters, so your `-h` part will be embedded into the docker run command. 
I didn't try it myself.

Another option would be to create an `ebextension` file to patch the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04run.sh` script, injecting the `-h MYHOST` line into it.

Comment: Looks interesting! I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I have same issue and struggling few days with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about single docker container deployment i.e v1 since i haven't tried that yet but they are definitely supported in v2 i.e multi container deployment. You can adda container hostname by putting below in `Dockerrun.aws.json` -

```
  "hostname": "this-is-my-container-hostname"
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I can't find it in the docs either.

Comment: After posting my previous comment I opened a support ticket and the AWS support representative came across this same StackOverflow post and confirmed that none of the methods answers on this page will work. The scripts have been deprecated in favor of their internal ECS agent. They recommended I explore ECS as it provides more control/options for this.

Comment: This looks like it's in the docs to me. The multi-container config for Elastic Beanstalk points out that the config file format is the same as ECS task definitions. That documentation supports a hostname parameter. Found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html It's also worth mentioning that you must have the "links" section in place and the networking has to be in bridged mode in order for these to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instance we patched old platforms with next script, but you can port it to new platforms. Example of `.ebextensions/01-docker-hostname.config`:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04a_set_hostname.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      hostname $(hostname -f | cut -d"." -f1,2)
      sed -i "s/docker run -d \\\/docker run -d -h $(hostname) \\\/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/04run.sh
```

As you see our script always patches the run script. EB run scripts in filename order. So you should be sure that your script runs before run script.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the hostname of the container by defining it as environment variable.

```
HOSTNAME=your-name
```